# Android In app billing getPurchases returns empty

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Currently I'm testing my app's in app billing. I'm trying to buy items and test signature verification etc. The problem comes when I need to purchase a item again: I consumed the purchase but it still says I own the product when I try to buy it and now after consuming the purchase once the getPurchases() method says I don't own anything. Am I doing something wrong here? Is it a bug in the V3 API? And if I can't consume the purchase from my app, can I consume it from somewhere else?

Consume purchase:

```
try {
    //Get purchases and consume them all                
    Bundle b = mac.service.getPurchases(3, package, "inapp", null);
    ArrayList<String> datalist = b.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
    for(String str : datalist) {
        JSONObject jpurchase = new JSONObject(str);
        String token = jpurchase.getString("purchaseToken");
        mac.service.consumePurchase(3, package, token);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Buy items:

```
//Get buy intent and send it
PendingIntent buyIntent = mac.service.getBuyIntent(3, package, purchasepopup.id, //purchasepopup.id = item id
                                           "inapp", "").getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

if(buyIntent != null) mac.startIntentSenderForResult(buyIntent.getIntentSender(),
                                       1002, new Intent(), 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is a bug in Google's API where if you start multiple buy intents at once before the first one ends, you can buy the item multiple times. And when you try to consume the item, it only consumes the first(or last) purchase and the rest are stuck on your account but won't show on queries.

How to fix:

Make sure your app only calls a buy intent when the user doesn't own it and only send one intent. If you have a item(s) stuck on account(s) and want to remove them you can either
1) Delete the bugged items from your app trough Google Play Console and create new ones (this is not good if you have already published the game on Google Play and somebody has bought a bugged item) or
2) Delete the items directly from your account (I don't know how to do this but it should be possible. If you know how to do this, please comment it, so I can add it.)

Comment: and how can you solve this problem? I'm in the position now that ```getPurchaes``` returns empty but Google says "you already own that item". How can I solve this?

Comment: @swalkner I'm not 100% sure but I think I had to delete the bugged items from the app and make new ones. And of course fix the code so that it isn't possible to buy items multiple times.

Comment: what do you mean by "delete the bugged items from the app"?

Comment: Delete the items that you have problems with from your Google play developer console.

Comment: but there's already a version of my app in the Play Store; that would mean that no one could purchase it any more, right?

Comment: Yes, but that's why you make a new one to replace it. But this will be a problem if someone has bought the item because they spent the money to get the bugged item and if you delete it, they will lose it. I don't know if there is a way to fix it without deleting the item. I don't know if you can query all the people that own the item and give them the new item for free, you should check if you can do this.

Comment: @swalkner what kind of in app purchase is it? Managed, unmanaged, or is it a subscription?

Comment: As far as I know this doesn't matter if you are using in-app billing V3 as unmanaged products are treated as managed in it. From V3 API specification: "When a user purchases a managed in-app item, Google Play stores the purchase information for each item on a per-user basis. This enables you to later query Google Play at any time to restore the state of the items a specific user has purchased." according to that you should be able to delete the items from a specific account directly without deleting it from your app.

Comment: If the order is a test purchase made through the In-app Billing Sandbox, orderId is blank. Checkout documentation at https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html